# Cannot install any R packages, unable to translate to native coding

Tags: r, directory, package, rstudio

Whenever I open Rstudio I get this message in red:

```
Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In list.files(cacheDir) :
unable to translate 'C:/Users/<U+03A7>a<U+03C1><U+03B7><U+03C2>/AppData/Local/RStudio/explorer-cache' to native encoding
2: In gzfile(file, mode) :
cannot open compressed file 'C:\Users\×áñçò\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEZExey\rstudio-available-packages-23783cacb6/time.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'.
```

My PC user name is written in a foreign language, but as you can see from the above text, Rstudio writes it as "×áñçò" wrongfully.

Whenever I try to install a package, Rstudio doesn't respond at all, and when I try to close it I get the message "Retrieving package installation context..." and I am stuck there for a while until I get this error in the console:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Warning in install.packages :
cannot create dir 'C:\Users\×áñçò\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpw9xEQw\downloaded_packages', reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : unable to create temporary directory ‘C:\Users\×áñçò\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpw9xEQw\downloaded_packages’
```

[image]

I have tried everything, from reinstalling, from running Rstudio as an administration but none of these work! Could you please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you install RStudio outside of C:\Users\your-name?

Comment: Please try @coffeinjunk's suggestion.  R in Windows handles non-Ascii characters very poorly; it's best to avoid them.